# How to send a data through json

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi guys i have been trying to use cURL to send and retrieve data.

I am new to php as only been doing this for about 3 weeks.

I have setup 2 variables from the database and when called from another site through cURL it should send them using json but for some reason it is not sending the data,

Could someone please tell me what i am doing wrong, everything works fine untill it gets to the json section and then it just does nothing.

code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['token'])){

$token = $_REQUEST['token'];
$url = $_REQUEST['www'];

$token = trim(htmlentities($token));
$safetoken = mysql_real_escape_string($token);
$url = trim(htmlentities($url));
$safeurl = mysql_real_escape_string($url);

$checkwebsite = "SELECT message,islive FROM websitetokens WHERE url='".$safeurl."' AND token='".$safetoken."'";
$checkwebsite_result = mysql_query($checkwebsite) OR die();
$numberofrows = mysql_num_rows($checkwebsite_result);

if($numberofrows > 0){

    $website = mysql_fetch_array($checkwebsite_result);
    $message = stripslashes($website["message"]);
    $islive = stripslashes($website["islive"]);

    json_encode(array('message' => $message,'islive' => $islive,));

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = gmdate('H:i');

    $loginwebsite = "UPDATE websitetokens SET loggedin='".$date."',time='".$time."' WHERE url='".$safeurl."' AND token='".$safetoken."'";
    $loginwebsite_result = mysql_query($loginwebsite) OR die(mysql_error());

} else {

    json_encode(array('message' => '','islive' => '1',));

}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there will be an output if you `echo` the result of `json_encode`. Also, it may also be wise if you set the content type of the output like so:

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
echo json_encode(array('message' => '','islive' => '1',));
```

Comment: when i put this, nothing is shown on screen or in source files: echo json_encode(array('message' => '','islive' => '1',));

Comment: possible reason is that the condition `if(isset($_REQUEST['token'])){` was not satisfied

Comment: it works fine as when i enter a valid one it updates the database but again as soon as it reaches the json_encode it stops working, with no errors. If i echo the variables out they all echo but when i echo the json_encode it does not.

Comment: check the version of your php and ensure that json is enabled, in PHP 5.2 I believe it is enabled by default. [JSON](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php)

If you're not seeing the json functions on 5.2.0 or newer, make sure php wasn't compiled with --disable-json

Comment: json is not even installed on the server :( we pay over £200 a month for this dedicated and it doesnt even have standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` returns the data, it doesn't do output, try using

```
echo json_encode(...);
```

instead.

Comment: I have tried this: echo json_encode(array('message' => $message,'islive' => $islive,)); and it does not echo anything, i have tried print_r() also and nothing :(

Comment: Is the db query working at all? Change the `or die()` to `or die(mysql_error())` so you can see if something DID blow up there.

Comment: Yes, if i echo the variables before it is going into the json file it works 100% but after its in the json_encode it does not work.

Comment: Try `echo json_last_error()` then to see if the encoding failed

Comment: Try doing a hard-coded `echo '{}'` or something, then, to see if something's interfering with the output.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode returns a string with the data in JSON format. Add echo to those lines (i.e. echo json_encode(array( ...)

Comment: i have done and it does not show any string, not even blank string :(